# Use communication channel in Wind River VxWorks Simulator

Tags: vxworks

I have a host PC and a target hardware.  On the host PC, I have .NET application and on the target I have a real time process, the target and the host communicates using Ethernet channel.

What I want to do now is to run the real time process on the vxsim.

Is there a way to make the process (running on vxsim) communicate with the .NET application that runs on the same PC.

P.S.
I use VxWorks 6.6 and Workbench 3.0

Answer (score 1):

You can run vxsim on your Windows machine and communicate with it over IP using simnet. See the VxWorks Simulator userguide for how to set this up.

Answer (score -1):

For this you would need a vxworks simulator that can be provided in full source code format which then can be compiled with hooks using .NET native tools. Such a simulator is provided by MapuSoft:
http://www.mapusoft.com/os-simulator/
Regards,
Raj